# Method to locate sibling key within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

A newbie to Ember.js trying to locate the sibling within a param.

I'm using a JSON file located at this [url](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/) that lists all the different Steam games that has the name and appid.  See below for example:

```
{
                "appid": 730,
                "name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"
            },
```

We currently have an action where when we enter in a name, it will search JSON page, but I'm still struggling a proper way to get the appid.

Any advice, or pointing me in the right direction, would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var appid;
var list = JSON.parse(dataFromUrl.applist.apps.app);
var findAppIDFromTitle = function(title){
    for(item in list) {
        if (item.name === title) appid = item.appid;
        // this is an alternative to find sub-title
        // if (item.name.split(':')[1].trim() === title) appid =  item.appid;
    })
}
findAppIDFromTitle('Counter-Strike: Global Offensive');
console.log(appid);
// alternative call
// findAppIDFromTitle('Global Offensive');
```

Comment: I tested this, but I get the error "dataFromUrl is not defined".  I feel like I'm missing something  and need to add something else for it to work.

Comment: @AndrewR dataFromUrl is the data you would get back from that URL you have above. I assume you are using AJAX to get the data. So change dataFromUrl to whatever you named the data in the ajax response

Comment: We actually haven't touched AJAX at all, but I'm currently reading some documentation that [looks promising](https://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html).